# Dynamic columns with jasper reports

Tags: java, excel, csv, jasper-reports

I have a CSV/Excel report with 5 fixed columns and I want to add more columns, depending on the input. Each report generation may require different number of columns.

The jrxml approach is done, so my question is - Can I add dynamic columns in jrxml ?

If not, what is the correct way to do it with coding ? [example](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/noxmldesign/index.html)

**Note**: I prefer not to use Dynamic Jasper library

Comment: How about generating the jrxml, i.e. the inputstream for `JasperCompileManager.compileReport()`, on the fly? ... or is this what you meant by "The jrxml approach is done"?

Comment: it is done for the 5 fixed (static) columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your purpose can be best achieved by using **DynamicJasper** which creates report design and layout on the fly. This will allow you to custom made report before generating it.

Answer (score 0):

DynamicJasper is perfect for generating a report having dynamic number of columns.
Here is one code which I used for my N number of columns and M number of rows to create a pdf file by using JRBeanCollectionDataSource.

```
private List<DynaBean> convertDynaBListFrom2DAry(Object[][] ary2D, int width, int height){
    logger.info("Converting report array to dynamic bean as, we have dynamic number of columns");
    DynaProperty[] props = new DynaProperty[width];
    for (int p=0; p < width; p++) {
        DynaProperty dp = new DynaProperty("property"+p);
        props[p] = dp;
    }
    List<DynaBean> dynaBeans = new ArrayList<>(height);
    for (Object[] objects : ary2D) {
        MutableDynaClass dc = new LazyDynaClass("Row", null, props);
        try {
            DynaBean row =  dc.newInstance();
            for (int c=0 ; c < width ; c++ ) {
                Object obj = objects[c];
                if(obj == null) {
                    obj = new String("");
                }else if(obj.equals("null")) {
                    obj = new String("");
                }else if(obj.equals("NaN")){ 
                    obj = new String("");
                }
                row.set("property"+c, obj);
            }

            dynaBeans.add(row);

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error("Exception ",e);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            logger.error("Exception ",e);
        }
    }
    return dynaBeans;
}
```

Comment: Alekya, Due to security reason I can not share complete code but you can have a look into DynaProperty and PropertyUrils from org.apache.commons.beanutils which are referred in DynamicReportBuilder to add each column detail which are generic and generated using DynaBean.